# Linq why does concatenating strings result in a null?

Tags: c#, linq

I thought that `"bill" + "john" + null == billjohn`, but in this example of mine it seems to be evaluating to null:

```
 var clients = from client in taxPortalService.Client()
                          select new ClientViewModel
                              {                               
                                  ResidentialAddressLine1 = client.RESADDRESSLINE1,
                                  ResidentialAddressLine2 = client.RESADDRESSLINE2,
                                  ResidentialAddressLine3 = client.RESADDRESSLINE3,
                                  ResidentialAddressLine4 = client.RESADDRESSLINE4,
                                  ResidentialPostalCode = client.RESPOSTCODE,
                                  ResidentialCountry = client.RESCOUNTRY,
                                  IAResidentialAddress = client.RESADDRESSLINE1 + ", " + client.RESADDRESSLINE2 + ", " + client.RESADDRESSLINE3 + ", " + client.RESADDRESSLINE4 + ", " + client.RESPOSTCODE + ", " + client.RESCOUNTRY                               
                              };
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C#, or rather in .NET, you're right, `"bill" + "john" + null` gives you `"billjohn"`.

In SQL, `'bill' + 'john' + null` gives you `null`.

Using LINQ to Entities translates your C# to SQL, and subtle differences such as this aren't always preserved.

You can use the more verbose

```
(client.RESADDRESSLINE1 ?? "") + ", " + (client.RESADDRESSLINE2 ?? "") + ", " + ...
```

to make sure you only concatenate non-null strings, which won't have this problem.

Answer (score 8):

I'm guessing this is using LINQ-to-SQL or EF as a backend, and it is generating SQL. Well, in TSQL a `null` concatenated with anything is (by default): `null`. Perhaps try:

```
(row.Foo ?? "") + ", " + (row.Bar ?? "") + ...
```

or easier: get the data as values into memory first, *then* do compositions.

Comment: Ah yes it is using SQL server and EF and is returning an ObjectQuery<T>. I was trying to avoid getting the whole dataset into memory as I wanted to apply paging without returning all data

Comment: @woggles that's fine - you do the paging, get your page into memory, *then* do the composition. I fully agree you don't want to load the entire table, but I didn't suggest that.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming SQL-Server as rdbms, a quick test reveals:

```
select 'A' + NULL;  // NULL
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7126)

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx)

> The + (String Concatenation) operator behaves differently when it
>   works with an empty, zero-length string than when it works with NULL,
>   or unknown values. A zero-length character string can be specified as
>   two single quotation marks without any characters inside the quotation
>   marks. A zero-length binary string can be specified as 0x without any
>   byte values specified in the hexadecimal constant. Concatenating a
>   zero-length string always concatenates the two specified strings. **When
>   you work with strings with a null value, the result of the
>   concatenation depends on the session settings. Just like arithmetic
>   operations that are performed on null values, when a null value is
>   added to a known value the result is typically an unknown value, a
>   string concatenation operation that is performed with a null value
>   should also produce a null result**. However, you can change this
>   behavior by changing the setting of CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL for the
>   current session. For more information, see SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL
>   (Transact-SQL). If the result of the concatenation of strings exceeds
>   the limit of 8,000 bytes, the result is truncated. However, if at
>   least one of the strings concatenated is a large value type,
>   truncation does not occur.